# Automatically copy text when selected it in c#

Tags: c#

It is possible automatically copy text when selected or highlight I mean only selected then copy to clipboard in c# ? thank you very much
like this question [C# , detect selected text on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803535/c-sharp-detect-selected-text-on-windows)
but I can't use the code of above answer of question

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  What platform?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net?

Comment: Windows form in c# @SLaks I need just retrieve the text when I selected or I highlighted it

Comment: When selected in what?

Comment: So you're actually asking about _Javascript_.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if it's a Windows Forms application, consume the `GotFocus` event and issue this command:

```
Clipboard.SetData(((TextBox)sender).Text);
```

If it's a Web Forms application then you'll need to use JavaScript. You'll need to consume the `focus` event of the text box:

```
<input type="text" focus="copyToClipboard(this);" />
```

and then you'll want this JavaScript:

```
function copyToClipboard(obj) {
    var text_val=eval(obj);
    text_val.focus();
    text_val.select();
    if (!document.all) return; // IE only
    r = text_val.createTextRange();
    r.execCommand('copy');
}
```

The problem with the JavaScript is that it doesn't actually work in **every** browser. See, the problem with the JavaScript approach is that you'll need code for all the browsers **and** you need to make sure that the user doesn't have JavaScript turned off. It progressively gets more complex.

Reference this post for more information on clipboard work in JavaScript, [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript).

Comment: This javascript only works in IE (less than 10), might as well remove that bit from your answer. Don't know anyone anymore who is writing a web app for IE8 only (for example).

Comment: @EkoostikMartin, actually I have over 14K+ customers that still use IE 8/9. I would say that the paragraph I leveraged after the code snippet is the most important part of the JavaScript implementation. Many use Flash objects - but there's a problem there because not everybody has flash. In short, the fragmentation on browsers, operating systems, and user settings make it nearly impossible to reach *everybody* with a JS implementation.

Comment: Forcing users towards a browser/OS is a mistake for any web app (even intranet/internal) especially if its IE. I should have said this in my original comment, but also I don't think copy/paste is relevant to any web based app. The clipboard is an OS subsystem, interaction with it should be completely restricted by any self respecting browser. Copy/Paste within the browser itself makes sense, maybe HTML6? Just my opinion of course.

Comment: Don't feature-test on unrelated objects.

Comment: @SLaks, I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.

Comment: @neoistheone: `document.all` has nothing to do with `execCommand()`.  You should check for `execCommand()`, not an unrelated property.

Comment: @SLaks, now I understand what you're saying. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's why god invented the `Clipboard.SetText` method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz40084e.aspx It works both on Windows and Linux (Mono), I don't know about Mac OS X

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `GetText` isn't going to **set** data on the Clipboard.

Comment: You right but I need get copy of text when select text only select not use right click then copy or ctr+c :)

Comment: Modified to `SetText` :P

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to handle the Validate event and pass the SelectedText property to the clipboard.  something like this:

`Clipboard.SetData("{0}",((TextBox)sender).SelectedText);`